# Regex: Change the order of words in text randomly (shuffle-words)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this sentence:

`Omul se poate combina multor gandiri-cu ideile cu ajutorul povestilor clasice corespunzatoare FAPTELOR si sensului abstract.`

Want to change the order of words, randomly, and become something like this:

`ideile poate  se multor  gandiri-cu combina Omul si povestilor abstract ajutorul corespunzatoare  FAPTELOR cu sensului clasice.`

I have a regex, the problem is that the last 2 words do not change. Maybe someone edit my regex, or make a better solution (much simple and more effective):

SEARCH:

`([\w-]+)[^\w\r\n-]+([\w-]+)[^\w\r\n-]+([\w-]+)[^\w\r\n-]+([\w-]+)[^\w\r\n-]+([\w-]+)[^\w\r\n-]+([\w-]+)[^\w\r\n-]+([\w-]+)`

REPLACE BY:

`\7 \3 \9 \2 \5 \8 \6 \4 \1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Not totaly random.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G\h+)([^\s.]+)(\h(?1))?(\h(?1))?(\h(?1))?(\h(?1))?(\h(?1))?(\h(?1))?(\h(?1))?(\h(?1))?(\.)?`
- Replace with: `$7$3$9$2$5$8$6$4 $1$10`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/GTl3KL/1)

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: it's ok Toto, thanks. But,  if I want more variants of solution, and if I give Replace All, it gives me an extra space between words. How could that extra space not appear after giving "Replace All?

And, what if the sentences have more then it show in my example?

If I add 3 words, or if I delete 3 words from my sentence above, your regex will not will not combine words very well. Maybe it must be change the sintax in the "replace with" in order to combine much better those words?

Comment: take a look here, it mix very well. https://onlinerandomtools.com/shuffle-words Something like that, Toto.

Comment: @JustMe: see my edit.